# Cmake vs The command line: Error in Cmake, not in command line

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, glfw

I have a c++, opengl project.  I have been compiling using the command line with this command:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags glfw3` -o test test.cpp Third_Party/glError.cpp Third_Party/glUtil.cpp  Third_Party/gl_core_4_3.cpp Third_Party/glTexture.cpp Third_Party/glShader.cpp `pkg-config --static --libs glfw3` -std=c++11
```

I wanted to use cmake instead, so I created this file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(openGLTest)

add_definitions(-std=c++11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

add_executable(openGLTest test.cpp Third_Party/glError.cpp Third_Party/glUtil.cpp  Third_Party/gl_core_4_3.cpp Third_Party/glShader.cpp Third_Party/glTexture.cpp)


find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

pkg_search_module(GLFW REQUIRED glfw3)
include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(openGLTest ${GLFW_STATIC_LIBRARIES})
```

When I compile and run test thru the command line, the project runs fine.  But when I compile and run openGLTest using cmake, I get this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
what():  basic_string::_S_create
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Why does this happen and what can i do to fix it?

Comment: `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` equal to *Release* may add additional compilation/linker flags. You may see full compilation line with `make V=1`. These addtional flags normally doesn't break **correct** programs, so having problem with them usually means that you program is incorrect. E.g., it uses some actions which leads to *Undefine Behavior*.

Comment: That is a little unclear to me.  Are you saying there is an error that isn't caught by the command line program but is caught by the cmake program?

Comment: `there is an error that isn't caught by the command line program but is caught by the cmake program?` - Yes, exactly that. More precise, this is error that is not caught by compilation with some set of flags, but caught by other set of compiler flags.

Answer (score 0):

1.- **add_definitions(-std=c++11)**, is wrong here because add_definitions is not intended for this. See the bottom example of [cmake-compile-features](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html#manual:cmake-compile-features(7)) so you can know how enable propertly c++11 features.

2.- **But when I compile and run openGLTest using cmake**, I don't see a run or test target created with cmake, did you miss that part of code in CMakeLists.txt?

My solution would be, either post complete CMakeLists.txt and/or clear cache files generated from cmake and build again. See if configuration and build times output errors or warnings.

Comment: not sure what you are talking about in your second point.  What I have posted is the entire cmake file

Comment: I was able to figure it out.  Thank you for your help.  It was a code related problem.  Since I was using cmake, the location of the program execution changed, which required me to change the path to my text files.  Since my program was not finding the correct text files, it was throwing this error, which I did not recognize.  Thank you again.